# Find sufficient statistic for a mixed distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

If I have a random variable $Y$ with a mixed distribution:
$$
F(y)=\begin{cases}
0, & y<1\\
1/\theta^3, &y=1\\
y^3/\theta^3, &1<y<\theta\\
1, &y\le\theta
\end{cases}
$$
and what I want to do is to find the sufficient statistic for $\theta$. If I do not consider the point where $y=1$, I could get p.d.f. and use [Factorization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher.E2.80.93Neyman_factorization_theorem) to get the sufficient statistic as $\max(Y_i)$. But, am I right to ignore that point?

Comment: If sample size is $1$, then $Y$ is trivially sufficient for $\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the Factorization Theorem, as the p.d.f can be written :
$$\begin{aligned}f(y) &= 2y^2/\theta^3\mathbb{I}_{y>1}\mathbb{I}_{y<\theta} + 1/\theta^3\mathbb{I}_{y=1} \\
&= 2y^2/\theta^3\mathbb{I}_{y>1}\mathbb{I}_{y<\theta} + 1/\theta^3\mathbb{I}_{y=1}\mathbb{I}_{y<\theta} \\
&= \mathbb{I}_{y<\theta}/\theta^3 \left(2y^3\mathbb{I}_{y>1} + \mathbb{I}_{y=1} \right).
\end{aligned}$$
Thus, $Y$ is a sufficient statistic.

Comment: If you merely "believe" your assertion, it's not really an answer. My guess you are a humble sort of person (which we need more of here at MSE), but if you are confident about your answer, start out with "You can use...". Best to you.

Comment: There is no pdf here.